# App from playstore run but same apk crashes on sideload install

Tags: google-play-store, security, installation, apk, side-loading

On my noughat device, I have downloaded app from playstore, which is running great. Extract apk from install app, uninstall it and again succussfully install with package installer. But second time on app launch, it crashes. I have analyse both installation with apk analyzer. First one showing com.android.vending as installer and application source as "Google Play". Sideload installation showing com.google.android.packageinstaller and source Unkown.

My first thought is that developer dont want to install app from unknown source to avoid MOD app or pirate release etc. and checking programatically for these parameter. I have decompile to java but no found any clue where condition is checking and exception generated.

There is a permission BIND_GET_INSTALL_REFERRER_SERVICE, may be its causing crash. I know how to decompile and some smali editing and alread change verifyinstallation method to true in smali but app still crashing.

Comment: If it is a paid app the app may simply check if your Google account has a valid license for the app. This is AFAIK the way Google recommends for app developers to protect their app from being pirated.

Comment: Thanks robert. its not paid app. There us no license issue. App developer made it secure to be install only from playstore. There are many tools available on playstore, which extract apk file from installed app. if somehow, we uninstall app then extracted/backup apk can directly install same app. Each appncan be install and use in thus manner, but first time, i have seen app, which function as expected when we install it from platstore, but not work properly or hang, same app install from apj (sideload)

Comment: App is clickmate, if anyone check and test it

Comment: Please do not only post the app name (which can be ambiguous). Always post the PlayStore link to the app you are talking about. I found a "clickmate" app in PlayStore and it has In-App purchases. Hence it is something like a paid app. May be what you have observed is just a bug.

Comment: In-app is simply google billing system, which is used for purchasing additional feature of app, or converting free version to premium or pro version. If its game them levels can be unlocked, coins/gold can be purchase. Wherese PAID APP mean it can not be downloaded, until we pay before it. Therefore clickmate offering sone feature in free version. Its not bug because app somewhere in its code and module, checking for installation source and I did not found these checking in decompile code